# Difference-in-difference with border areas: how to create indicator for matched area?

Tags: difference-in-difference, research-design

I'm trying a DiD by comparing adjacent districts which lie on two sides of state border, before and after a policy. The scheme is following: state A introduced a policy in year t, while state B (adjacent state) did not. Now, state A has a district p (say) which shares a border with districts q and r of state B. The idea is comparing outcomes between p and q,r before and after period t. So district p after t is treatment group, while q,r form control group.

It might also happen that two treatment districts in state A share border with same control district in state B and I'm not sure what to do in such situation

I have come across such a design earlier but currently I'm at a loss and can't think of any paper that uses this design so that I may look it up.

I want to know how to match these treatment and control districts and would appreciate any help. Please reply on this thread if you feel this question needs more clarification and I'll update with any relevant information.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. In what sense do you mean “matching” here? Are you speaking in a statistical sense or in a more general case where you create dummies for districts that border the treated areas?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in "MINIMUM WAGE EFFECTS ACROSS STATE BORDERS:
ESTIMATES USING CONTIGUOUS COUNTIES" by Dube, Lester and Reich, which implements as differences-in-differences design using border county pairs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).